# printf implementation in c, my function prints two extra spaces

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my own `printf` function, I'm testing my code with two flags `-+`, my `handle_d_i()` function prints two more unneeded spaces. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int str_contains(char c)
{
    static char conversions[] = "sSpdDioOuUxXcC";
    int         i;

    i = 0;
    while (conversions[i])
    {
        if (c == conversions[i++])
            return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}

void    putnbr(int n)
{
    if(n >= 10)
    {
        putnbr(n / 10);
        putnbr(n % 10);
    }
    else
    {
        putchar(n + '0');
    }
}

int flags(char flag, char *search)
{
    while (*search)
    {
        if (*search == flag)
            return (1);
        search++;
    }
    return (0);
}

void    handle_d_i(char *f, int d_i)
{
    int i;
    int l_justfy;
    int force_pos;

    l_justfy = flags('-', f);
    force_pos = flags('+', f);
    i = atoi(f + (l_justfy + force_pos));
    if (l_justfy)
    {
        if (force_pos)
            putchar('+');
        putnbr(d_i);
        while (--i > 0)
            putchar(' ');
    }
    else
    {
        while (--i > 0)
            putchar(' ');
        if (force_pos)
            putchar('+');
        putnbr(d_i);
    }
}

void    my_printf(char *format, ...)
{
    char    *traverse;
    va_list arg;
    int     i;
    char    *flags; 

    va_start(arg, format);
    i = 0;
    flags = malloc(strlen(format));
    traverse = format;
    while (*traverse)
    {
        if (*traverse == '%')
        {
            i = 0;
            traverse++;
            bzero(flags, strlen(flags));
            while (!str_contains(*traverse))
                flags[i++] = *traverse++;
            if (*traverse == 'd' || *traverse == 'i')
                handle_d_i(flags, va_arg(arg, int));
            // handle more flags
        }
        else
            putchar(*traverse);
        traverse++;
    }
    va_end(arg);
}

int     main(void)
{
    my_printf("|%-+9d|%13d\n", 18,9 );
    printf("|%-+9d|%13d", 18,9 );
    return (0);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|+18        |            9
|+18      |            9
```

[example](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/YFg4vR)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You're not counting the characters you are outputting against your field width.  You're also not dealing with negative numbers properly, so your function is really handle_u rather than handle_d_i

Comment: You also have a memory leak.  You're calling `malloc` and never freeing the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing out a number, but you are not subtracting the number of digits and sign from the width specifier (`i`).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it, by subtracting the number of digits form `(i)`, as suggested by `MSN`.

```
void    handle_d_i(char *f, int d_i)
{
    int i;
    int l_justfy;
    int force_pos;
    int num_digits;

    l_justfy = flags('-', f);
    force_pos = flags('+', f);
    i = atoi(f + (l_justfy + force_pos));
    num_digits = strlen(itoa(i));
    if (force_pos)
        i = i - (num_digits + 1);
    if (l_justfy)
    {
        if (force_pos)
            putchar('+');
        putnbr(d_i);
        while (--i > 0)
            putchar(' ');
    }
    else
    {
        while (--i > 0)
            putchar(' ');
        if (force_pos)
            putchar('+');
        putnbr(d_i);
    }
}
```